# Cypress - How can I verify if the downloaded file contains name that is dynamic?

Tags: cypress

In cypress, the xlsx file I am downloading always starts with lets say "ABC" and then some dynamic IDs. How can I verify if the file is downloaded successfully and also contains that dynamic name?
Secondly, what if the downloaded file is like "69d644353f126777.xlsx" then how can i verify that the file is downloaded when everything in the name is dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any way to know what the generated name will be@

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way that suggests itself is to query the downloads folder with a task,

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

on('task', {
  downloads:  (downloadspath) => {
    return fs.readdirSync(downloadspath)
  }
})
```

**test**

```
cy.task('downloads', 'my/downloads/folder').then(before => {

  // do the download

  cy.task('downloads', 'my/downloads/folder').then(after => {
    expect(after.length).to.be.eq(before.length +1)  
  })
})
```

If you can't direct the downloads to a folder local to the project, provide a full path. Node.js (i.e Cypress tasks) has full access to the file system.

---

To get the name of the new file, use a filter and take the first (and only) item in the result.

```
const newFile = after.filter(file => !before.includes(file))[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. 
Another similar question.. How can I upload the same file from downloads folder and the file has the dynamic name? Thank again

Comment: You're welcome. To get the name of the new file, use a filter one the after arraymand take the first (and only) item in the result. `const newFile = after.filter(file => !before.includes(file))[0]`

Comment: ok thanks. File to upload is in downloads folder but when I try to upload it requires fixture path and getting this error.
A fixture file could not be found at any of the following paths:

> cypress\fixtures\E:\Projects\CypressAutomation\cypress\downloads\ABC12345.xlsx

Comment: Sorry I messed up that previous comment.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are doing the upload, presume the app was doing it? Looks like you are doing it in the test with `cy.fxture()`? Would be better to show the whole scenario in the question.

Comment: Can anybody provide the Typescript version for Cypress 10? I fail in specifying it in the setupNodeEvents function in cypress.config.ts.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to leverage Nodes `fs.watch(...)` API and to define a plugin task which waits for a new download to be available and returns the filename:

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    getDownload: () => {
      const downloadsFolder = config['downloadsFolder'];
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const watcher = fs.watch(downloadsFolder, (eventType, filename) => {
          if (eventType === 'rename' && !filename.endsWith('.crdownload')) {
            resolve(filename);
            watcher.close();
          }
        });
        setTimeout(reject, config.taskTimeout); // Or another timeout if desired
      });
    },
  });
};
```

And then it is fairly easily used within a test spec as follows:

**/sometest.spec.js**

```
it('downloads a file', () => {
  cy.get(downloadButtonSelector).click();
  cy.task('getDownload').then(fileName => {
    // do something with your newly downloaded file!
    console.log('Downloaded file:', fileName);
  });
});
```

Now technically there may be a bit of a race condition if the file is downloaded extremely quickly and the file exists on disk before the watcher begins, but in my testing - even with relatively small files and fast network speed - I have never observed this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will works but this also requires a filename to be assert.Write this code in index.js

```
on('task', {
        isExistPDF(PDFfilename, ms = 4000) {
          console.log(
            `looking for PDF file in ${downloadDirectory}`,
            PDFfilename,
            ms
          );
          return hasPDF(PDFfilename, ms);
        },
      });
```

Now add custom command in support/commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('isDownloaded', (selectorXPATH, fileName) => {
  //click on button
  cy.xpath(selectorXPATH).should('be.visible').click()
  //verify downloaded file
  cy.task('isExistPDF', fileName).should('equal', true)
})
```

Lastly write this code in your logic area

```
verifyDownloadedFile(fileName) {
    //Clear downloads folder
    cy.exec('rm cypress/downloads/*', {
      log: true,
      failOnNonZeroExit: false,
    })
    cy.isDownloaded(this.objectFactory.exportToExcelButton, fileName)
  }
```

and call this function in your testcase

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something similar to @user14783414.
However I keep getting that the downloads' folder length was 0. I then added an `cy.wait()` which solved the issue.

```
cy.task('downloads', 'my/downloads/folder').then(before => {
  // do the download
  }).then(() => {
    cy.wait(500).then(() => {
      cy.task('downloads', 'my/downloads/folder').then(after => {
    expect(after.length).to.be.eq(before.length +1)  
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For the solution of Nicholas, in firefox, the '.crdownload' doesn't exist so we need to add a condition on the '.part' :

```
if (eventType === 'rename' && !filename.endsWith('.crdownload') && !filename.endsWith('.part'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it thanks to this suggestion on Github: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14863#issuecomment-809191446

It's using the `fs.readdirSync` with a Cypress plugin `cypress-wait-until` so you can use it like this in your test:

```js
cy.waitUntil(() => cy.task('getLastDownloadFilePath')).should('not.be.empty');
```

Here's the code for reference (I did not write it myself, thanks [TomaszG](https://github.com/TomaszG) for finding the workaround):

```js
// plugins/index.js
const path = require('path');
const { existsSync, readdirSync, lstatSync } = require('fs');

const downloadsDirPath = 'cypress/downloads';

const getLastDownloadFilePath = () => {
  if (!existsSync(downloadsDirPath)) {
    return null;
  }

  const filesOrdered = readdirSync(downloadsDirPath)
    .map(entry => path.join(downloadsDirPath, entry))
    .filter(entryWithPath => lstatSync(entryWithPath).isFile())
    .map(fileName => ({ fileName, mtime: lstatSync(fileName).mtime }))
    .sort((a, b) => b.mtime.getTime() - a.mtime.getTime());

  if (!filesOrdered.length) {
    return null;
  }

  // TODO: this works only for chrome family browsers
  if (filesOrdered[0].fileName.indexOf('crdownload') > -1) {
    return null;
  }

  return filesOrdered[0].fileName;
};
```