# Cypress identify the downloaded file using regex

Tags: javascript, path, cypress

I have one scenario where I have to verify the downloaded text file's data against an API response.

Below is the code that I have tried.

**Test:**

```
const path = require('path')
const downloadsFolder = Cypress.config('downloadsFolder')
cy.task('deleteFolder', downloadsFolder)
const downloadedFilename = path.join(downloadsFolder, 'ABCDEF.txt')//'*.txt'
....
  cy.get('@portmemo').its('response.body')
    .then((response) => {
      var json = JSON.parse(response);
      const resCon = json[0].content.replaceAll(/[\n\r]/g, '');
      cy.readFile(downloadedFilename).then((fc) => {
        const formatedfc = fc.replaceAll(/[\n\r]/g, '');
        cy.wrap(formatedfc).should('contains', resCon)
      })
    })
```

**Task** in /cypress/plugins/index.js

```
const { rmdir } = require('fs')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    console.log("cucumber started")


    on('task', {
        deleteFolder(folderName) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                rmdir(folderName, { maxRetries: 5, recursive: true }, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return reject(err)
                    }
                    resolve(null)
                })
            })
        },
    })
```

When I have the *downloadedFilename* as 'ABCDEF.txt', it works fine [I have hard coded here].  But I need some help to get the (dynamic) file name as it changes every time [eg.: AUADLFA.txt, CIABJPT.txt, SVACJTM.txt, PKPQ1TM.txt & etc.,].

I tried to use '*.text' but I get '*Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.readFile("C:\Repositories\xyz-testautomation\cypress\downloads/*.txt") failed because the file does not exist* error.

I referred to this [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) as well but no luck yet.

What is the right way to use regex to achieve the same? Also wondering is there a way to get the recently downloaded file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the task shown in this question [How can I verify if the downloaded file contains name that is dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68083504/8745435)

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');

on('task', {
  downloads:  (downloadspath) => {
    return fs.readdirSync(downloadspath)
  }
})
```

This returns a list of the files in the downloads folder.

Ideally you'd make it easy on yourself, and set the [trashAssetsBeforeRuns](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Downloads) configuration. That way, the array will only contain the one file and there's no need to compare arrays before and after the download.

(Just noticed you have a task for it).

Comment: BTW `const path = require('path')` looks like NodeJS, does it work ok in the test?