# How to check Download of file with unknown name, in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my application, I am testing a download function that works by clicking a button. I know I can check if a download of a file with a known name happened with:

```
cy.readFile(path.join(downloadsFolder, "tickets.pdf")).should("exist");
```

But how can I check if a different pdf is downloaded into the same folder, while I don't know the name of the pdf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress - How can I verify if the downloaded file contains name that is dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68082896/cypress-how-can-i-verify-if-the-downloaded-file-contains-name-that-is-dynamic)